# App crashes while creating a Firebase Database instance

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My Android application crashes while creating an instance for the Firebase Database.

I have checked the database url in the google-services.json file and it seems to be fine.I tried debugging my app and the problem seems to be occurring due to line 45 of the SignIn.java, the code for which I have placed below.

SignIn.java:

```
    package com.example.androideatit;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.androideatit.Model.User;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

    public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtPhone,edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);




    try{

        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);


        //Init Firebase
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");


        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
                mDialog.show();

                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //Check if user exists in database
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            //Get User information
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                            if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }catch (Exception ex){
    Log.e("Error is",ex.getMessage());}



    }
   }
```

Error messages (Run log):

```
07/29 14:46:19: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\KONGKAN\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidEatit\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.androideatit
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.androideatit"
Success
APK installed in 3 s 223 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.androideatit/com.example.androideatit.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 12583 on device motorola-moto_g__5__plus-ZY223ZC3KT
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.androideatit-2/lib/arm
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.androideatit.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:23)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6672)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:757)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.androideatit-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.androideatit-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.androideatit.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:23)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6672)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:757)
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.androideatit, 1:906299679021:android:d8941acf196c56e0
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.androideatit
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1841367578815156332}]
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : bc479b6, I15255e4b4a
    Build Date                       : 02/22/17
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.5.R1.07.00.00.269.019
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 750358358
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3568
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 750361926
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3568, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1841367578815156332}]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.androideatit, PID: 12583
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.androideatit-2/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.androideatit.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than initiating the Firebase instance in Activity class initialize it in your application class which extend **Application** and add it to manifest as **android:name=".AppNameClass"**.

Also try to **downgrade your current library** version like if it is **17.0.0 then downgrade to 16.0.1** or somewhat and again test it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two issues not only the firebase startup, the first one is your view is not able to resolve this method:

```
Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
```

are you using the API 28?

the second one, firebase database should be instantiated and used as reference as the docs explains:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write